# PHP - Looking for a way to compare a value in two dimensional array, then combine arrays with same value to form a three dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-push

am looking for a way to achieve result of the above title.
I have a two dimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reference_no] => A0012
            [code] => HSWH30
            [net_unit_price] => 24000
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reference_no] => A0012
            [code] => HSWH15
            [net_unit_price] => 21000
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [reference_no] => A0013
            [code] => HS-106AR
            [net_unit_price] => 2400
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [reference_no] => A0013
            [code] => HS-8012
            [net_unit_price] => 4500
            [quantity] => 2
        )
)
```

And am looking for a way to compare arrays using the [reference_no] value, then add arrays with same [reference_no] in inside an array, thereby forming a three dimensional array as shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_no] => A0012
                    [code] => HSWH30
                    [net_unit_price] => 24000
                    [quantity] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference_no] => A0012
                    [code] => HSWH15
                    [net_unit_price] => 21000
                    [quantity] => 2
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_no] => A0013
                    [code] => HS-106AR
                    [net_unit_price] => 2400
                    [quantity] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (

                    [reference_no] => A0013
                    [code] => HS-8012
                    [net_unit_price] => 4500
                    [quantity] => 2
                )       
        )
)
```

Please I need a quick help, have tried using for loop and array_push to compare and merge/combine similar array, but am not getting the result that I need.

Comment: When you post a question with a large array it's always better to json encode it or var_export it. We can't use the data you posted here.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to loop the array and create a new associative array with the ref no as the key.
This will group the items as you want, and when the loop is done you reset the index of the array with array values.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $new[$sub['reference_no']][] = $sub;
}
$new = array_values($new);
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["reference_no"]=>
      string(5) "A0012"
      ["code"]=>
      string(6) "HSWH30"
      ["net_unit_price"]=>
      string(5) "24000"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["reference_no"]=>
      string(5) "A0012"
      ["code"]=>
      string(6) "HSWH15"
      ["net_unit_price"]=>
      string(5) "21000"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["reference_no"]=>
      string(5) "A0013"
      ["code"]=>
      string(8) "HS-106AR"
      ["net_unit_price"]=>
      string(4) "2400"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["reference_no"]=>
      string(5) "A0013"
      ["code"]=>
      string(7) "HS-8012"
      ["net_unit_price"]=>
      string(4) "4500"
      ["quantity"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DQEmC

Comment: Thanks @Andreas this is useful

Comment: So does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try lets say:

```
 $arrayExample[0] => Array
                ( [reference_no] => A0013
                        [code] => HS-8012
                         [net_unit_price] => 4500
                         [quantity] => 2 )
```

so technically speaking the value of `$arrayExample[0]["reference_no"] is A0013`
if so why not use

```
if( strpos($arrayExample[0]["reference_no"],"A0013") !==false)
{
    $arrayExample[0]["reference_no"] = array( 
[0] = //something
[1] = //something1
...
)}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The reference_no value is dynamic, don't see this helping.

Comment: `$arrayExample = Array
(
    'reference_no' => 'A0012',
    'code' => 'HSWH30',
    'net_unit_price' => 24000,
    'quantity' => 2
        );
echo $arrayExample['reference_no'];
$arrayExample['reference_no'] = array('newData'=>12345, 'exampleData'=>56789);
echo '</br>';
echo $arrayExample['reference_no']['newData'];
echo '<br>';
echo $arrayExample['reference_no']['exampleData'];
$arrayExample['reference_no']['exampleData'] = array('anotherData' => 'something');
echo '<br>';
echo $arrayExample['reference_no']['exampleData']['anotherData']; `

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new associative array, and use the reference_no as the keys. Then it's much easier to check if the key exists in the new array.

```
$sorted = [];

foreach($array as $el) {
  $ref = $el[reference_no];
  if (array_key_exists($ref, $sorted)) {
    $sorted[$ref][] = $el;
  } else {
    $sorted[$ref] = [$el];
  }
}
```

If you needed to convert $sorted to have a sequential numeric index (0,1,2,3 ...), you could do that as a final step with array_map, or another foreach loop.